# iOS keyboard and Textfields

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextfield

Evening, I have an app with several `UITextfield`, like always, when I press on a textfield I have the keyboard's position issue.

I know that I have to solve it with delegates and the `textFieldDidBeginEditing func`, to move up the textfield of `250` and than down again.

But usually I did it with with an easy layout, in this one there are severals nested `stack views` and I really don't know how to fix this. I read that I should use `scroll view`, I've tried but it screw up all the layout. Tips? I like so much the coding challenges but when it's about layout stuff, the hate come outside and my brain freeze.

[image: The Layout of the App]

## Solution:

### In Auto Layout

1 Add a **screen sized view** on top of all

2 Add **constraints** to the new view

- Leading edge equal to leading edge of superview.
- Bottom edge equal to bottom edge of superview.
- Equal widths with superview.
- Equal heights with superview.

3 Make the **proper constraints adjustments** on the subViews/StackViews

4 Set all the **textfield with delegates** on the view controller

### In Code - ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var mainViewBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var activeField: UITextField?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
        
    
    }
//we are tracking the Field we are working on
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        activeField = textField
    }
    
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
    {
        activeField = nil
    }
    
    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let userInfoDict = notification.userInfo, let keyboardFrameValue = userInfoDict[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
            let keyboardFrame = keyboardFrameValue.cgRectValue
            
            //The view will scroll up only for the following textfield

            if activeField == zipCodetext || activeField == cityText || activeField == streetAddresstext || activeField == stateText {
            
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8) {
                    self.mainViewBottomConstraint.constant = keyboardFrame.size.height
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8) {
            self.mainViewBottomConstraint.constant = 0
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to [@vacawama](https://stackexchange.com/users/1789974/vacawama)

Comment: How about putting your entire layout in a screen sized view, and then just moving that view up by the right amount when the keyboard appears?

Comment: Well, is it possible? this seems so easy :P

Comment: It's possible.  It's easy if you start out that way.  It's more difficult to insert a layer if you already have the UI laid out and constraints set.

Comment: Ok, now i have a top main view, and how can I move it up with code? I assume with constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your entire layout in a screen sized view, and then just moving that view up by the right amount when the keyboard appears.

Drag out a `UIView` and place it in your top level view.  Resize it to be the size of the screen.

Set 4 constraints:

1. Leading edge equal to leading edge of superview.
2. Bottom edge equal to bottom edge of superview.
3. Equal widths with superview.
4. Equal heights with superview.

Create an `@IBOutlet` to the bottom constraint.  When the keyboard appears, set `bottomConstraint.constant = 250` to move the view up.  Set it back to `0` to move it back down again.  You might need a negative value for the `constant` depending on the ordering of the items in your constraint.

---

To animate the move, call `layoutIfNeeded` on `self.view` in the block for `UIView.animateWithDuration`:

```
bottomContraint.constant = 250
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0) {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've edited the question with your solution and with other tips :)